# python keyerror with dataframe loc and apply lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I have a dataframe with two columns `ProductID` and `Balance`.
Some `Balance` columns have `values =0 (df['Balance']=0)`.
My dataframe contains different products:

```
Index ProductID Balance

1        10     100

**2      20     0**

3        30     200

**4      20     150

5        20     240**

6        40     100

7        30     200
```

I want to impute the zero balance at index 2 with average balance based on the `product ID=20 ((0 +150 + 240)/3 =130)` .

I am using the below code:

1. First getting the `balance_average` based on the ProductID:

   `balance_average = df.pivot_table(values='Balance', index='ProductID')`
2. Identifying the zero balance rows:

   `zero_bool = (df['Balance'] == 0)`
3. Applying balance_average:

   `df.loc[zero_bool, 'Balance'] = df.loc[zero_bool, 'ProductID'].apply(lambda x: balance_average[x])`

When I execute the code above in python 3.6 I am getting 
`KeyError: '20'`.
20 is the corresponding ProductID of the first zero balance column.
Could someone tell me what's wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because you're reading 'balance_average' like a dictionary within your apply code (which is what you need to do - convert balance_average to a dict).

Can you try?:

```
 balance_average = df.pivot_table(values='Balance', index='ProductID')
 bal_avg_dct = balance_average.to_dict()
 ....
 df.loc[zero_bool, 'Balance'] = df.loc[zero_bool, 'ProductID'].apply(lambda x: balance_average[x])
```

Comment: tried the below code, still getting KeyError:20.                             zero_bool = (df['Balance'] == 0)                                                                                  
                                                                                            balance_average = df.pivot_table(values='Balance', index='ProductID'),                                                                  balance_average_dict = balance_average.to_dict(),
df.loc[zero_bool, 'Balance'] = df.loc[zero_bool, 'ProductID'].apply(lambda x: balance_average_dict[x])

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get a KeyError is because you are accessing the `balance_average` wrongly, if you `print (balance_average)`, you will get this:

```
>>> print (balance_average)
           Balance
ProductID         
10             100
20             130
30             200
40             100
```

Which is not the scalar that you want. You can access the value like this:

```
>>> print (balance_average['Balance'][20])
130
```

So your lambda function should be:

```
lambda x: balance_average['Balance'].[x]
```